# How to parse the list data in python

Tags: python, list, inspect

I have a list

```
[<class test1.C at 0x02BAF308>, <class test1.A at 0x02BAF0D8>]
```

Now i need to fetch only C and A from the list and  got this output by using     inspect.getmro(test1.C).here A and C refer to the class name .How can i retrieve only names from that list

Comment: You want to return only the names, so the result will be `['A', 'C']`?

Comment: yes ,I need it in the same way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the names of the classes, they are stored in attribute `__name__` of the class.

Minimal working example:

```
>>> class A(object): 
...     pass
... 
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getmro(A)
(<class '__main__.A'>, <type 'object'>)
>>> [c.__name__ for c in inspect.getmro(A)]
['A', 'object']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the names of the classes of the objects in a list, you can get them all fairly trivially;

the `class` type of any object is stored in the `__class__` attribute of the class. And then all `class` objects have a `__name__` attribute.

so;

```
itemClassNames = [item.__class__.__name__ for item in list]
```

If you just have the list of classes already, you can skip the **class** part, and just do

```
itemClassNames = [class.__name__ for class in list]
```